# Login form in drupal

Tags: drupal, authentication

I've got a problem with drupal 7. Since i moved my website to another server I can't use the login form anymore.

I can access with the url ?q=user, I see the form but all fields are disabeld. When I remove the disabled attribute with firebug and I valid the form nothing happened..

I've searched on google and I didn't see any post like that, does someone have an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: May be this will help you : [Moved Drupal 7 site to a different server, can't log in][1] or [After moving my Drupal 7 site to another host, modules are appeared without download][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125299/moved-drupal-7-site-to-a-different-server-cant-log-in
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211597/after-moving-my-drupal-7-site-to-another-host-modules-are-appeared-without-down

Answer (score 0):

Are your Apache rewrite rules working on the new environment?

1. Check that your .htaccess file is present and that your hosting allows you to have some overrides.
2. Check that the mod_rewrite module is enabled on your new Apache server.

You may need to go back in Drupal's admin pages to disable and re-enable the clean URLs.

Oh, and did you change and forget to adjust your `$cookie_domain` variable in your `settings.php` file in case your domain is different?